# calling one method from another under same js object

Tags: javascript

I wrote some js:

```
var folersTreeMgr = {

    sendDeleteFolderRequestAndUpdateFoldersTree: function () {
       ...

        } else {
            createAjaxRequest("Manager/DeleteLocation", {
                'locationId': folder_minimal_descriptor.locationId
            }).done(function (isSucceeded) {

                if (isSucceeded) {

                    folersTreeMgr.deleteFolderInFoldersTree(); // works
                    this.deleteFolderInFoldersTree(); // doesn't work
                    deleteFolderInFoldersTree(); // doesn't work
                }

                //TODO: else: error
            });
        }
    },


    deleteFolderInFoldersTree: function () {
        $("#jstree").jstree("remove", null);
    }
};
```

why do I get "missing function" error

Comment: *"why do I get...saw this post, but it didn't help."* **Huh?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you're using `this` inside a callback, where it has different meaning.

You can referene the outer `this` in a variable, then use that in the callback.

```
var folersTreeMgr = {

    sendDeleteFolderRequestAndUpdateFoldersTree: function () {

       var self = this;  // cache it

       ...

        } else {
            createAjaxRequest("Manager/DeleteLocation", {
                'locationId': folder_minimal_descriptor.locationId
            }).done(function (isSucceeded) {
                if (isSucceeded) {
                   self.deleteFolderInFoldersTree(); // works
                }
            });
        }
    },
    deleteFolderInFoldersTree: function () {
        $("#jstree").jstree("remove", null);
    }
};
```

---

Or use `$.proxy` to keep the `this` value...

```
createAjaxRequest("Manager/DeleteLocation", {
    'locationId': folder_minimal_descriptor.locationId
}).done( $.proxy(function (isSucceeded) {
    if (isSucceeded) {
       this.deleteFolderInFoldersTree(); // works
    }
},this) );
```

This'll return a function that has the second argument to `$.proxy` bound to the function passed as the first argument.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `this.deleteFolderInFoldersTree()`, you are in a different context, which means `this` is no longer the object. A quick way to solve this is the following:

```
var self = this;
```

Then do `self.deleteFolderInFoldersTree()`

Comment: This is another issue with his code, but he's creating an object literal, so ``this`` means ``window`` and ``self.deleteFolderInFoldersTree()`` will still fail in his case.

Comment: @DavidEllis: The fact he's creating an object literal doesn't mean that `this` will be `window`; the two things are completely unrelated. (`this` may well be `window` within the function passed into `done`, but that depends **entirely** on how the callback passed into `done` is called, nothing to do with it being a literal.)

Comment: Well I'll be... I'm mistaken, then, but that produces even more oddities when dealing with nested objects, or an object literal inside of a constructor function...

Comment: @DavidEllis: Not really. Remember, `this` (in JavaScript) [is defined entirely by *how a function is called*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html), not where or how the function is defined. It's fundamentally different from `this` is some other languages, like C++, Java, or C#.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder [yes, I'm right on that new interpretation](http://jsfiddle.net/JetEe/)